# Reg-ex won't print

Tags: python, regex

I can't seem to print the dates. The idea is that I'm able to extract all dates in a string, but the dates won't print

```
import re

# Define a regular expression to match dates in different formats
date_regex_1 = re.compile(r'''
    # Match dates in the format: August 2nd, 1994
    (?P<month>\w+)               # Match the month name
    \s+                          # Match one or more whitespace characters
    (?P<day>\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th) # Match the day number and its suffix
    ,\s+                         # Match a comma and one or more whitespace characters
    (?P<year>\d{4})              # Match the year
    # Ignore any trailing characters
    \b                           # Match a word boundary
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

date_regex_2 = re.compile(r'''
    # Match dates in the format: august 2, 1994 or 08/02/1994 or 08-02-1994 or 08/02/94
    (?P<month>\d{1,2}|\w{3})     # Match the month number or abbreviation
    [\s/-]                       # Match a space, forward slash or dash separator
    (?P<day>\d{1,2})             # Match the day number
    [\s/-]                       # Match another separator
    (?P<year>\d{2}|\d{4})        # Match the year

    # Ignore any trailing characters
    \b                           # Match a word boundary
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)



# Define a regular expression to check if a date is valid
valid_date_regex = re.compile(r'''
    # Match a valid date in the format: mm/dd/yyyy
    (0[1-9]|1[0-2])              # Match a month from 01 to 12
    /                            # Match a forward slash separator
    (0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])        # Match a day from 01 to 31
    /                            # Match another forward slash separator
    (19\d{2}|20\d{2})            # Match a year from 1900 to 2099
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

# Define a list of dates to test
dates = 'August 2, 2022, mar 6, 2013'


# Extract all valid dates from the list and format them as mm/dd/yyyy
valid_dates = []

for date in date_regex_1.finditer(dates):
    print(date.group())
for date in date_regex_2.finditer(dates):
    print(date.group())
```

Tried to format it in groups, in for loop. Dates won't print. Any Ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any data in your sample that matches either of those patterns.

In the first pattern, you are specifying that the day portion *must* include 'st', 'nd', 'rd', or 'th' after the number. The test data does include any strings that match.

The second pattern is looking for mm/dd/yyyy, neither of the test dates match that pattern.

If you change the input data (dates) to:

`dates = 'August 2nd, 2022, mar 6th, 2013, 04/22/2020'` (line 40) then all three of those are output.

If what you wanted was for the letters after the day to be optional (i.e. mar 6 and mar 6th are **both** valid), then the pattern needs to change.

You could make line 8 `(?P<day>\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)*` but that feels imprecise, maybe `(?P<day>\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th){0,1}`.

The edited script below outputs three dates

```
import re

# Define a regular expression to match dates in different formats
date_regex_1 = re.compile(r'''
    # Match dates in the format: August 2nd, 1994
    (?P<month>\w+)               # Match the month name
    \s+                          # Match one or more whitespace characters
    (?P<day>\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th){0,1} # Match the day number and its suffix
    ,\s+                         # Match a comma and one or more whitespace characters
    (?P<year>\d{4})              # Match the year
    # Ignore any trailing characters
    \b                           # Match a word boundary
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

date_regex_2 = re.compile(r'''
    # Match dates in the format: august 2, 1994 or 08/02/1994 or 08-02-1994 or 08/02/94
    (?P<month>\d{1,2}|\w{3})     # Match the month number or abbreviation
    [\s/\-]                       # Match a space, forward slash or dash separator
    (?P<day>\d{1,2})             # Match the day number
    [\s/\-]                       # Match another separator
    (?P<year>\d{2}|\d{4})        # Match the year

    # Ignore any trailing characters
    \b                           # Match a word boundary
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)



# Define a regular expression to check if a date is valid
valid_date_regex = re.compile(r'''
    # Match a valid date in the format: mm/dd/yyyy
    (0[1-9]|1[0-2])              # Match a month from 01 to 12
    /                            # Match a forward slash separator
    (0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])        # Match a day from 01 to 31
    /                            # Match another forward slash separator
    (19\d{2}|20\d{2})            # Match a year from 1900 to 2099
''', re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)

# Define a list of dates to test
dates = 'August 2nd, 2022, mar 6, 2013, 04/22/2020'


# Extract all valid dates from the list and format them as mm/dd/yyyy
valid_dates = []

for date in date_regex_1.finditer(dates):
    print(date.group())
for date in date_regex_2.finditer(dates):
    print(date.group())
```

Outputs:

```
August 2nd, 2022
mar 6, 2013
04/22/2020
```

Comment: Thank you! I've had a hard time with formatting the regex, and it was originally in one regex instead of two as a *challenge*. I'll take a look at my regex to see what I can fix. Thanks again!